# Python Remove all Lines starting with specific word

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string that contains:

```
ASFksdfasf a
Oh sadfafas
Yeasd: asdfaf
Oh asdfaf
```

And I want to delete the lines from the string that start with "Oh". How exactly would I approach this? Right now I know I can do something in regex similar to this:

```
\b[Oh]\S*
```

But I am unsure on how to store this result to a variable, and even then, I believe it only finds the words, not deletes them.

Comment: Just as a heads up, `/^Oh.*/m` is what you're looking for...I'd still use @AvinashRaj's answer.

Comment: @Sam do you know how I can store that regex result into a variable?

Comment: @user2677095 `reg = r'^Oh'` `if not re.match(reg, stri):`

Comment: @user2677095 I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `string.startswith` function.

```
if not string.startswith('Oh'):
```

Example:

```
>>> s = '''ASFksdfasf a
Oh sadfafas
Yeasd: asdfaf
Oh asdfaf'''
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
    if not line.startswith('Oh'):
        print(line)


ASFksdfasf a
Yeasd: asdfaf
```

Comment: Can I use this function to store all the lines that don't start with 'Oh' into a new variable? It's not necessary for my case, but would be a helpful touch.

Comment: Never mind, I think your newly edited post will work fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I commented on OP with the expression you'd use to do this, but suggested going with @AvinashRaj's answer (non-regex). You asked how this would be implemented, and [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is the answer!

---

Demo:

```
string = '''ASFksdfasf a
Oh sadfafas
Yeasd: asdfaf
Oh asdfaf'''

import re
print re.sub(r'^Oh.*\n?', '', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Outputs:

```
ASFksdfasf a
Yeasd: asdfaf
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the heads up. I'm sure it'll come in use in the future!

Comment: Always to use the flags=... identifier with the re.sub method. Otherwise you end up setting the count!
Good solution